# Using immutable, deduplicated EntityTypes in EF

Tags: entity-framework, immutability

Suppose I have a CRUD application that lets a user manage their album collections:

```
class Collection
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    List<Album> Albums //EF navigation property
}

class Album
{
    int Id;
    List<CdCase> Cases; //EF navigation property
    string Name;
    string Artist;
}
```

In this application, I let users add, edit, and delete albums to their collections. The collections and albums are stored in a SQL Server database using Entity Framework.

Naively implemented, there are going to be a lot of duplicate albums, so I'd like to do the following at collection-save time:

- Deduplication: If an album already exists (as determined by Name/Artist equality), the collection uses that album instead of creating a new one
- Immutability: If an album is edited, the edits are not persisted to the server. Instead, the album is removed from the case and a new one is created/linked.
- Garbage Collection: If an edit/delete operation results in an album no longer being in any collection, it is deleted from the database entirely.

Is there a way to implement this logic at the DBContext level (i.e. changing the `Set<Collection>` behavior), rather than manually cleaning up the albums before submission?

**EDIT** I am using code-first EF 6.1.

Comment: I think this belongs in stored procedures that you attach to the create/update/delete actions of the entities.

Comment: Depends on EF version and code-first/db-first.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx